# Convert XML to CSV in PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv

Is there a way to convert an XML file to a CSV using PHP?

Comment: can you also post your xml sample?

Comment: XML can contain hierarchical data, while CSV only tabular data. So it really depends on your XML.

Answer (score 13):

Use search engines to locate code samples such as http://codestips.com/php-xml-to-csv/

To create a csv file from a xml in PHP 5.0 it’s very simple, we will just have to write some lines.

We will use the SimpleXML extension that come from PHP 5.0.

SimpleXML reads an entire xml into an object that we can iterate through his properties.
To write to the csv output file we will use fputcsv.

fputcsv formats a line as csv and writes it to the file.

Suppose we are having this xml named cars.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<cars>
<car>
 <color>blue</color>
 <price>2000</price>
</car>
<car>
 <color>red</color>
 <price>10000</price>
</car> 
<car>
 <color>black</color>
 <price>5000</price>
</car>
</cars>
```

First we should read our xml using simplexml_load_file passing the name of the file and returns an object with all the properties and values of the csv:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
```

After reading it we should iterate through all the child nodes of cars and write it to the output file using fputcsv specifying the object,delimiter and enclosure. We should first convert the object into an array in order to write it to the csv:

```
foreach ($xml->car as $car) 
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($car),',','"');
```

Here is the complete source code that converts xml to csv in php 5.0:

```
<?php
$filexml='cars.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('cars.csv', 'w');
foreach ($xml->car as $car) {
    fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($car),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
?>
```

Comment: I was going to up-vote... until I saw you use `short_open_tag` :] *(Short tags are ebil!)*

Answer (score -2):

Here is a very good code example. working fine with my rquirement.

```
<?php
$headers = array();
foreach ($xml->ROW->children() as $field) {
    $headers[] = $field->getName();
}
$filename = '';
$csv_filename = str_replace('xml', 'csv', $filename);
$file = $this->getCsvDirectory() . '/' . $csv_filename;

$csv = fopen($file, 'w');
fputcsv($csv, $headers, ',', '"');
foreach ($xml as $entry) {
    $data = get_object_vars($entry);
    $sanitized_data = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $datum) {
        $sanitized_data[$key] = html_entity_decode($datum, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    }
    fputcsv($csv, $sanitized_data, ',', '"');
}
fclose($csv);
?>
```